# jQuery selector troubles - trying to select and log links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors

I'm making a Chrome extension that acts on Facebook's newsfeed. I'm trying to select the URL starting with "https://external-ort2-2.xx" from Facebook's "_q7o" div and log it to the console (function capturePic). The earlier code, which inserts a button after the "_q7o" div, works fine, so I think I'm selecting the right div. But URL isn't getting logged.

Many thanks!

```js
function callAttentionToX(jNode) {
var uCW = jNode.closest("div._q7o");
var button = document.createElement("a");
button.innerHTML = "I'm a button";
button.style.float= "left";
uCW.append(button);
}

function capturePic(jNode) {
var uCW = jNode.closest("div._q7o");
var firstHref = $(".uCW a[href^='https://external-ort2-2.xx']").attr("href");
console.log(firstHref);
}

waitForKeyElements("[aria-label$='Story options']", callAttentionToX, capturePic);
```

Comment: Maybe if you show us the HTML too it would be easier to see the issue

Comment: It's a Chrome extension that works on the Facebook newsfeed (I'll add that to the question)